# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date "Fri Sep 12 23:22:46 IST 2014"

Tags: java, json, jackson, simpledateformat, mongo-jackson-mapper

I am using jackson mapper to map the json request to an java object directly. To map the date i am using CustomDateSerializer and CustomDateDeSerializer in the getter and setter respectively.

```
public class CustomJsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
        String dateString = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
        jsonGenerator.writeString(dateString);
    }
}


public class CustomJsonDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {
    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser,
                            DeserializationContext deserializationcontext) throws IOException {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
        String date = jsonparser.getText();
        try {
            return format.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

my getter and setter in the model

```
@JsonSerialize(using=CustomJsonDateSerializer.class)
    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomJsonDateDeserializer.class)
public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
}
```

Exception:

```
Could not read JSON: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Sep 12 23:22:46 IST 2014"
```

Can any one help me fixing this..

Comment: Well it clearly doesn't match that date format...

Comment: oh yes, i got it, "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy" this will match with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format which you have defined is:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

However it looks like the format which it is expecting is not the same(**Fri Sep 12 23:22:46 IST 2014**).

It should be like:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss Z yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Check the [Oracle docs for SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change

`SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");`

to

```
SimpleDateFormat dF=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the date format fixed it - "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"